# can't apply custom validation to requestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, controller, http-request-parameters

I have my RequestParam and I need to validate it, but mu custom validation don't apply, my controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
class ExchangeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExchangeController.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiredFieldsWarningInspection")
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataService")
    private CurrencyExchangeService currencyExchangeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Object converting(@RequestParam("fromCurrency") @NotNull @CurrencyValidation String fromCurrency,
                             @RequestParam("toCurrency") @NotNull String toCurrency,
                             @RequestParam("amount") @NotNull String amount) throws IOException {
        BigDecimal convertedAmount = currencyExchangeService.convert(fromCurrency, toCurrency, new BigDecimal(amount));
        return new ExchangeRateDTO(fromCurrency, toCurrency, new BigDecimal(amount), convertedAmount);

    }
}
```

and custom validation

```
public class ConstractCurrencyValidator implements
            ConstraintValidator<CurrencyValidation, String> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(CurrencyValidation currency) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String currency, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            return currency != null && Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance(currency));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your `CurrencyValidation` class and what is your expected outcome here?

Comment: @rimonmostafiz
I'm expect that if I input not currency I will receive 400 error

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @rimonmostafiz
not applicable to parameter

Comment: Is there any ConstraintViolationException in the log?

Comment: @rimonmostafiz
no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197165/discussion-between-rimonmostafiz-and-qwerty).

Comment: @qwerty you need an `@valid` for the validations to usually work on the pathparameters. Let me know if that solved your issue

Comment: Your method should typically look like ```public Object converting(@Valid @RequestParam("fromCurrency") @NotNull @CurrencyValidation String fromCurrency...```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

need to put an annotation in my `@interface CustomValidation`. This means that validation can also be used on the parameter.

```
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
```

Comment: Include all this in your question, so that it might help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Enable parameter validation in config:

```
 @Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}
```